# Change one reference to letters instead of numbers

Tags: biblatex

Is it possible to change one reference to letters instead of numbers?
I am writing a report on statics, and would like only one reference to be [TS] instead of [2].
Is that possible? can i renew command? or is that not possible with references? i am using the biblatex package.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Kilder.bib}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `shorthand` field:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
 @manual{xkeyval,
  title = {The \texttt{xkeyval} package},
  subtitle = {Extension of the keyval package},
  author = {Adriaens, Hendri},
  url = {http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xkeyval},
  urldate = {2020-07-05},
  date = {2014-03-12},
  shorthand = {XKV},
  version = {2.7a}
 }
 @manual{etoolbox,
  title = {The \texttt{etoolbox} Package. An e-\TeX{} Toolbox
   for Class and Package Authors},
  author = {Philipp Lehman and Joseph Wright},
  url = {http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox},
  urldate = {2020-07-05},
  date = {2019-09-21},
  version = {2.5h}
 }
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,sorting=none,locallabelwidth]{biblatex}
  \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
 See \cite{xkeyval} or \cite{etoolbox}
   \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey @Ivan, thanks, ill try it out!

Question: Which part goes into the preamble and which part goes to the references.bib ?

Comment: `\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,sorting=none,locallabelwidth]{biblatex}` and \addbibresource... in the preamble; `shorthand=TS`  in the bibliography entry. Look at the example: it should be self explanatory, I hope